# Windows 8 context menu and taskbar thumbnails don't stay visible

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, thumbnails, synaptics-touchpad

I installed Windows 8 on an old Laptop that came pre-installed with Windows Vista.

This is what CPU-Z says about my configuration:

[image]

The touch-pad is using Synaptic drivers.

The issue is whenever I hover over the task-bar icons in Windows 8 File Explorer, the live-thumbnails don't stay visible, they almost instantaneously hide. This is frustrating. If I'm Window 8 Metro app and try to use the context menu within the app by right-clicking, the same thing happens. The context-menu shows up for less than a second and then hides. This is not so much frustrating because I don't use many Metro apps.

What could be the reason for this? This bugs my workflow.

Comment: I guess the CPU has no influence on your problem here (You can remove the screenshot of CPU-Z). But did you upgrade from Vista to Windows 8 or did you do a new Installation?

Comment: It was a fresh installation. @FiveO